# Checkout from subversion and discard actual local changes in NetBeans

Tags: svn, netbeans, netbeans-6.9

So I'm working on a project that is hosted on Google Code. Sometimes I use my desktop, other times I'm not home and I want to work on my laptop. To ease the development, I use subversion. To tell my problem, let's suppose the following scenario:
First I create the project on my laptop, and commit it to Google Code.
Next time I work on desktop computer, and I checkout the project and after doing some work I commit my changes.
Now I want to update my project on my desktop to have the latest version, but the only available action in the right click menu of my project is "commit".

So how should I do this?

*Note: Suppose that I also make some changes that I want to discard before the update.*

Comment: If you were using the command line version, the appropriate method would be to revert all the changes using `svn revert -R .` in the root directory of your working copy, followed by `svn up`. I'm not sure how to do the same thing from the GUI unfortunately -- I've always preferred the simplicity of the command line.

Comment: @Stuart It doesn't sounds like a revert to me

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Surely I can do this from the cli, I'm just wondering if NetBeans will see the changes. I'm ok with doing all the commands from the command line, but all I want is NetBeans to know what's going on with the project.

Comment: @RichardOD: He said "Suppose that I also make some changes that I want to discard before the update." Which seemed to me like a revert followed by an update -- am I missing something?

Comment: @s3v3n: 'fraid I can't help with that aspect of it, sorry -- I don't use NetBeans at all.

Comment: Ok, in this case how I set up the svn ok on my project, because the only active item in the right click -> subversion on my project is "commit".

Comment: @Stuart Golodetz. Sorry. I somehow didn't see that bit!

Comment: @s3v3n: Not sure on that one, sounds like a NetBeans issue rather than a Subversion one.

Comment: @Stuart Golodetz: That's why actually I tagged my question as NetBeans too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the command you're looking for is `revert`.

I'm using Subclipse, and I just right-clicked on the project, went to "Team", and selected "Revert..." and removed local changes (after confirming what was being removed).

Comment: Well, maybe. This question is more than a half year old and I switched  to git already :). Thanks anyway